# Batoo JPA, Spring and JodaTime

Tags: spring, jpa, jodatime, batoo

I've been checking out batoo JPA lately. I've managed to use it with Spring and it seems to work good with the standard JPA interface. Now I'm looking how to get JodaTime to get persisted transparently. 
I know that I can write a converter but I was wondering if maybe guys from the batoo team done some work on this. I've cloned the source and grep-ed it through but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for pointing out the issue.

As stated in the issue manager a snapshot has been released that should fix the issue.

Comment: Artificial setters and getters provide a workaround in that cases, but do you plan (especially in the near future :) ) to add support for type converters (like mentioned in JSR-338 chapter 11.1.10 Converter Annotation)?